# how to loop through list of files?

Tags: vimscript, plugin-vimwiki

I can do `:echo globpath('~/path/to/dir', 'string*')` to get a list like:

```
/home/alec/path/to/dir/string_xyz123.mkd
/home/alec/path/to/dir/string_xyz456.mkd
/home/alec/path/to/dir/string_xyz789.mkd
```

but now I want to loop through that and for each `/home/alec/path/to/dir/string_xyz123.mkd` that gets returned I want to `substitute` on them.

Doing...

```
  let fileList = globpath('~/Documents/wiki/subdir', 'string*')
  for fileName in fileList
    substitute(fileName, '/home/alec/Documents/wiki/subdir', 'newtext', '')
  endfor
```

...produces error "List required"

`:help for` and `:help while` haven't been much help.

How do I iterate through this list of files?

Comment: By `substitute`, do you mean a `:%s/oldtext/newtext/` command? If that's the case, you need to open the files into buffers... Please [edit] the question to clarify exactly what you want to do with the files (or the file names.)

Comment: @filbranden I updated the question to clarify this.  thanks for your time :)

Comment: Did you visually examine the generated list of paths? Sometimes it's not what you expect. Also, using `~` in vim may not work as expected for certain use cases. You may need to `expand()` it. (Or use `$HOME` or the full typed out path.)

Comment: are you looking for `:argdir` in conjunction with `:%s`? Perhaps it is easier to load all matching files into the quickfix window and then use `:cfdo :%s` etc.

Comment: Your question was originally about `List required` and I think @Matt's answer addressed that. Editing the question to make it about the next thing blocking you is not great (particularly once an answer addresses that)... Would you please edit it back to make about that (exclusively)? Then post a new question about the actual problem you're trying to solve. Thanks!

Comment: It seems you have some basic misconceptions on how Vimscript works, for instance you can't really call a function such as `substitute()` just like that, Vim thinks you're trying to use the `:substitute` (commonly used as `:%s/oldtext/newtext/`) since that's how Vimscript works (it executes Ex commands.) If you feel like you should learn Vimscript better (to help you accomplish what you're trying to do here), I strongly suggest the excellent
 ["Learn Vimscript the Hard Way"](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/).

Comment: You could also turn it around and make it about "Does Vimwiki support a feature to accomplish this thing I'm trying to do?" It's quite possible something like that already exists... Also, some Vimwiki authors/contributors/maintainers hang around here and might give you great advice on how to best accomplish what you want in Vimwiki...

Comment: @filbranden great thanks.  I'll do as you suggest once I'm able to mentally process the comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can do :echo globpath('~/path/to/dir', 'string*') to get a list like:

This is not a List. This is a long String with newlines.

To get a List you must supply the 4th argument as in [`:h globpath()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#globpath%28%29):

```
echo globpath('path', ''expr', 1, 1)
```

Comment: What's this `, 1, 1` extra arguments about?  It solves the problem like you said, but I read the `:help globpath` and couldn't understand.  Would you mind explaining it briefly in relation to this specific use of the command???

Comment: The last argument `{list}` defines whether to return a list or not, that's the one you actually need... The third argument `{nosuf}` is about whether to disable filtering of entries based on the `'wildignore'` and `'suffixes'` options. Note that 1 ("true") means to *disable* those filters, which is not the default behavior... You might want to pass `, 0, 1` instead (see example in `globpath()`). Also note that when they talk about "true", they mean a non-zero value (such as 1), while 0 indicates a "false" value. I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I noticed that both `, 0, 1` and `, 1, 1` worked.  Thanks for explaining about the {list} argument :)